# PHP Sort Array based on values in another

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - sort an array based on another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/php-sort-an-array-based-on-another-array)

Need some help regarding array sorting....

I have two arrays. The main one (where the key is the user id) :

$user[31] = 'Tom'

$user[43] = 'Jane'

and another array with the order they should be displayed (where key is the order and value is the user id) :

$order[1] = 43

$order[2] = 31

How can I apply the ordering to the main array using the ordering one?

Thanks guys!

Comment: @Fearghal: Thanks for the hint in the comments to my answer. I closed you question since it’s obviously a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Use the keys in `$order` to select the users from `$user` in the right order:

```
$orderedUsers = array();
foreach ($order as $key) {
    $orderedUsers[] = $user[$key];
}
```

Comment: got the answer right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/php-sort-an-array-based-on-another-array

Answer (score 0):

Use this one, it is usefull for your problem

```
$array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
print_r(array_values($array));
```

Result as :

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```