# php associative array key order (not sort)

Tags: php, arrays, associative

My array:

```
$data = array('two' => 2, 'one' => 1, 'three' => 3);
```

Now, with when I iterate the array, the first value that will come up will probably be

```
$data['two'] // = 2 @ index[0]
```

right?

What if I want to move the $data[1] to the position of $data[0] ?

To rephrase:

How do I make the array look like this (so that 'one' comes up at $data[0])

```
$data = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3
```

Why do I need this?

I use code igniter, the table->generate built-in function takes an assoc array and creates a table but offers no method of arranging the columns. This is why I would like to move the columns in the source array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an Array by keys based on another Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array)

Comment: @iautomation The question did not make any mention of using a second array to control the order of the first. They asked for a solution to control the order of the keys after the array has been created. Using another array MAY be one possible solution, but it should not be a limiting factor in finding solutions for this question.

Comment: why don't you want to sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [daniele centamore's comment](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php#92651) on PHP's [array_splice()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) function, where he provides a couple of functions for moving the elements in an **non-associative array**.

```
<?php

// $input  (Array) - the array containing the element
// $index (int) - the index of the element you need to move

function moveUp($input,$index) {
      $new_array = $input;

       if((count($new_array)>$index) && ($index>0)){
                 array_splice($new_array, $index-1, 0, $input[$index]);
                 array_splice($new_array, $index+1, 1);
             } 

       return $new_array;
}

function moveDown($input,$index) {
       $new_array = $input;

       if(count($new_array)>$index) {
                 array_splice($new_array, $index+2, 0, $input[$index]);
                 array_splice($new_array, $index, 1);
             } 

       return $new_array;
}  

$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

$newinput = moveUp($input, 2);
// $newinput is array("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")

$input = moveDown($newinput, 1);
// $input is array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow")

?>
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Daniele's example is not for associative arrays

Answer (score 24):

Two possible solutions (without using `array_splice`):

1) Create a new array with the new order of the keys.

```
$new_keys = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$new_data = array();
foreach ($new_keys as $key) {
    $new_data[$key] = $data[$key];
}
$data = $new_data;
```

2) Move the element `one` upfront, remove it from `$data` and copy the rest of the array.

```
function rearrangeData($data) {
    $result['one'] = $data['one'];
    unset($data['one']);
    return array_merge($result, $data);
}    
$data = rearrangeData($data);
```

Comment: Thank you! One suggestion to solution 1: If you have more keys as $new_keys have, it will strip the others completely. Maybe there should be a fallback and let the others "unsorted".

Answer (score 2):

See [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) and [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php).

Here's a working example:

```
<?php

$data = array('two' => 2, 'one' => 1, 'three' => 3);
print_r($data);
ksort($data);
echo "ksort:\n";
print_r($data);
uksort($data,'cmp');
echo "uksort:\n";
print_r($data);
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $num=' one two three four five six seven eight nine ten';
    $ai = stripos($num,$a);
    $bi = stripos($num,$b);
    if ($ai>0 && $bi>0) {
        return ($ai > $bi) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return strcasecmp($a, $b);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [two] => 2
    [one] => 1
    [three] => 3
)
ksort:
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [three] => 3
    [two] => 2
)
uksort:
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 2
    [three] => 3
)
```

Run this: 
http://codepad.org/yAK1b1IP

Answer (score 0):

PHP has [13 functions for sorting arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), by key, by value, by user-defined functions where you can specify that "one" comes before "two". There's also array_shift, array_unshift, array_push and array_pop for moving things onto or off the front or end of the array. You can build a whole new array from the existing one.

Comment: I know, these functions are great. However, notice how it says 'Not sort' in the title. 

Also, I couldn't find the function array_move_index('one',0);

Comment: Rearranging a set of items *is* sorting. Just because your ordering is not lexicographic or numeric doesn't mean arranging arrays in that order isn't sorting. That's the very meaning of the word.

Comment: Exacly, you should use usort and write a simple closure.

Comment: This vague hint of an answer should have been posted as a comment under the question.  It makes very little attempt to resolve the actual asked question.  If the question is too vague, then vote to close instead of answering.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should use asort function:

```
$data = array('two' => 2, 'one' => 1, 'three' => 3);

$dataOrdered = $data;
asort($dataOrdered);
```

[Run this code](http://codepad.org/rTtJmeJm)

Comment: This does not sort by key, it sorts by value! See here: http://codepad.org/wUAsV5hr

Comment: Question specifically requested a non-sort solution.