# Sorting an array by its keys by another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an array by its keys based on the order of the values in another array.
Simple example:

```
$sort_array = array( 'key1', 'key2' );

$array_that_needs_sorting = array( 'key2' => 'value2', 'key1' => 'value1' );
```

After sorting, the array should be:

```
array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at [Sort an Array by keys based on another Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-based-on-another-array). It should give you an idea on how to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried all functions in that topic before but it didn't work because my arrays weren't the same size

Answer (score 3):

If you know the `$sort_array` keys are all present in the array that needs to be sorted, you can do this:

```
$sorted = array_merge(array_flip($keys), $unsorted);
```

where `$keys` is `$sort_array` and `$unsorted` is `$array_that_needs_sorting`.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_merge(array_combine($sort_array, array_fill(0, count($sort_array), null))
   , $array_that_needs_sorting);
```