# PHP sort array by array, match key

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

My first array:

```
normalArray
(
    [0] => Business Class
    [2] => Economy
    [6] => First Class
)
```

My sorting array:

```
sortArray
(
    [0] => Economy
    [1] => Business Class
    [2] => First Class
)
```

I am trying to get this as my result

```
resultsArray
(
    [2] => Economy
    [0] => Business Class
    [6] => First Class
)
```

Note that the key and value needs to follow the correct order. So i would need to sort array by an array while keeping the key to the value.

I have searched around and looked at many different examples.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-based-on-another-array

Comment: @tony what u use for sorting array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$map = array_flip($sortArray);
uasort($normalArray,function($a,$b) use ($map) {return $map[$a] < $map[$b] ? -1 : 1});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) or [arsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

Example:

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
asort($fruits);
--OR--
arsort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
a = orange
d = lemon
b = banana
c = apple
```

For more **sorting function attributes** check out this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

may this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

Comment: Asort doesnt provide with the same results im looking for, the result order will need to be same as my other array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [arsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

Example:

```
 normalArray
(
    [0] => Economy
    [2] => Business Class
    [6] => First Class
)
```

The above example will output:

```
resultsArray
(
    [2] => Business Class
    [0] => Economy
    [6] => First Class
)
```

Comment: Doing a arsort or asort doesnt provide the result im asking for. The order will need to be same as my sorting array. Not just checking by alphabetical. Thanks 

resultsArray
(
    [2] => Economy
    [0] => Business Class
    [6] => First Class
)

Answer (score 0):

```
asort($normalArray);
```

this maintains the index of the array.

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php