# Sort an array based on another array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

according to this answer -> [Sort an Array by keys based on another Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-based-on-another-array), I use this function to get my another array sorted:

```
function sortArrayByArray($array,$orderArray) {
    $ordered = array();
    foreach($orderArray as $key) {
        if(array_key_exists($key,$array)) {
            $ordered[$key] = $array[$key];
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $ordered + $array;
}
```

at first, I have my code like this and it works fine

```
$array1 = array("a","b","c");
$array2 = array("2","5","1");
$array3 = array("2","5","1");
rsort($array3); //5,2,1

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $customer1[$array2[$i]] = $array1[$i];
}

$properOrderedArray1 = sortArrayByArray($customer1, $array3);

print_r($properOrderedArray1);
```

but when I use some logic math like multiply, it gets any errors like it said there is data type float

```
//multiply
$a = 100000*100000;
$b = 200000*200000;
$c = 300000*300000;

$array1 = array("a","b","c");
$array2 = array($a,$b,$c);
$array3 = array($a,$b,$c);
rsort($array3); //5,2,1

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $customer1[$array2[$i]] = $array1[$i];
}

$properOrderedArray1 = sortArrayByArray($customer1, $array3);

print_r($properOrderedArray1);

var_dump($array2);
```

**THE ERROR: Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer**

so any solution for this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: not sure about it, but 100000*100000 is way to big for an integer. therefore it is treated as float and that isn´t allowed as index.

Comment: but the main thing is, how to keep using the function if the the data type is float? or you have any functions to solve this problem?

Comment: @PeterPivarc - can you expain your comment with code here? :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you will have to convert your floats to strings. I guess you can alter your function to something like this to make it work:

```
function sortArrayByArray($array,$orderArray) {
    $ordered = array();
    foreach($orderArray as &$key) {
        if (!is_int($key))
            $key = number_format($key,0,'.','');
        if(array_key_exists($key,$array)) {
            $ordered[$key] = $array[$key];
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $ordered + $array;
}
```

The problem about doing it this way is that you lose precision in your float value. In a 64-bit system all these values

```
$a = 9223372036854775808;
$b = 9223372036854775809;
$c = 9223372036854775810;
```

will be converted into the same `float(9.2233720368548E+18)`, and converting it to a string will give `string(19) "9223372036854775808"`. As long as your indexes that you use for sorting have significant numbers in the upper range of the number it can work, but it's not a safe way of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what i written in the comment is true as i just checked in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

```
$large_number = 2147483647; //treated as int
$large_number = 2147483648; //treated as float since it is too large for an integer
```

So the solution to your problem is to limit the indices to the max value of integers.
OR to convert the floats to strings, but i would NOT recommend that, but sadly that seems to be the only way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't because it's according to the company's data, it has a lot of data with big numbers

Comment: then you have a problem and as far as i can see there is NO way to numeric indices, then you would have to use strings as keys as they are not limited in size/length.