# Sort object properties by name like another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

how can I sort object properties by name using another array as refer?

```
var json = '{"b":90,"c":42, "a":34}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var sorting = ["a","b","c"];
```

I would like to have *obj* properties ordered just like *sorting* array

Thank you

Bye

Comment: here you can find something similar in php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-based-on-another-array

Comment: The downvoted answer is the correct one, there is no guaranteed order in objects, so it can't be sorted, it's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sorting = Object.keys(obj).sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects are not ordered. So, you cannot actually sort them.

Comment: gravi is maybe looking for an algorithm to sort the json array, not a library function.

Comment: There's no such thing as json array. Also, he is trying to sort object which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just iterating over the array, and then access obj properties ?

```
for ( var i = 0; i < sorting.length; ++i ) {
  var current = obj[ sorting[ i ] ];
  // other stuff here...
}
```

If you don't intent to iterate over the obj, please explain your actual needs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert Object to Array

   var jsonArray = [];

   $.each(myObj, function(i,n) {
      jsonArray.push(n);
   });
2. Sort Array

   var jsonArraySort = jsonArray.sort();
3. Convert Array to Object

   var jsonSort = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonArraySort.length; i++) {
      jsonSort[i] = jsonArraySort[i];
   }

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
var sorted = []
for (i = 0; i < sorting.length; i++) {
  if (json.hasOwnProperty(sorting[i])) {
    sorted.push(json[sorting[i]);        
  }
}

/* sorted will equal [34, 90, 42] */
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot order the keys of an object, as per definition,

> An ECMAScript object is an **unordered** collection of properties<sub>[ES3 Specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)</sub>
>
> The mechanics and **order** of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) **is not specified.**
>
> Properties of the object being enumerated may be deleted during enumeration. If a property that has not yet been visited during enumeration is deleted, then it will not be visited. If new properties are added to the object being enumerated during enumeration, the newly added properties are not guaranteed to be visited in the active enumeration. A property name must not be visited more than once in any enumeration.<sub>[ES5 Specs](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4)</sub>

If you want to a sorted array consisting of your objects keys, you can use [`Object.keys`][4], To get an **array** of them, which you can then sort.

```
var obj = {b:90,c:42, a:34}
console.log (
      Object.keys (obj).sort ()
) // ["a","b","c"]
```

If you are interested in a sorted array, containing both, keys and values, you could do the following.

```
var obj = {b: 90, c: 42, a: 34},
    srt = Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function (prop) {
              return {
                  key: prop,
                  value: obj[prop]
              }
          });

console.log(srt) //[{"key":"a","value":34},{"key":"b","value":90},{"key":"c","value":42}]
```