# Array sorting based on another index value in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

```
$number=array(1212,340,2310,670,90);            
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Maruti","Zen");
```

I need to sort `$number` array from high to low, which I am doing using `rsort`. I want to sort `$cars` based on sorted index value of `$numbers` and echo it. Like:

```
$number=array(2310,1212,670,340,90); //sorted values
$cars=array("Toyota","Volvo","Maruti","BMW","Zen") //then display these values
```

I guess I need to use `$order` as mentioned in this answer [Sort an Array by keys based on another Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-based-on-another-array) but I am still not able to figure out. I don't want to combine the 2 arrays. I want to sort an array based n index value of other array.

Comment: First merge the arrays so that first array becomes the key and second array becomes respective values for the new array, then sort them based on keys

Comment: There is no direct correlation between those two arrays, and therefore there is no way for you to establish a relationship between the two arrays unless you start using indices. Basically what @hjpotter92 said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [multisort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) should to it:

```
$number=array(1212,340,2310,670,90);
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Maruti","Zen");

array_multisort($number, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $cars);

var_dump($cars);
```

Output exactly as you want it:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Toyota"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Volvo"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Maruti"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "BMW"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "Zen"
}
```

Comment: You can output it any way you want. You asked about sorting, that's what multisort is for. `echo implode('<br />', $cars);` will echo it.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just told you what I wanted. :P I can do it on my own

Answer (score -1):

You need `array_combine`...

Here's an example:

```
<?php
    $number=array(1212,340,2310,670,90);            
    $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Maruti","Zen");
    $newarray = array_combine($number, $cars);

    print_r($newarray);
?>
```

results in:

```
Array ( [1212] => Volvo [340] => BMW [2310] => Toyota [670] => Maruti [90] => Zen )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score -1):

Use a multidimensional array and then Sort it:

```
<?php        
$cars=array(1212=>"Volvo",340=>"BMW",2310=>"Toyota",670=>"Maruti",90=>"Zen");
krsort($cars);
foreach ($cars as $key => $val) {
echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```