# PHP sort an array by key by another array(table)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array as table:

```
$sortLikeThis = [
    '5',
    '3',
    '7'
    '1',
];

$unsorted = [
    [
        'sort' => '7',
        'name' => 'Test',
    ],
    [
        'sort' => '1',
        'name' => 'Test 2',
    ],
    [
        'sort' => '3',
        'name' => 'Test 3',
    ],
    [
        'sort' => '5',
        'name' => 'Test 4',
    ],
    [
        'sort' => '7',
        'name' => 'Test 4',
    ],
]
```

I want to get sortered array ($unsorted) by sort key like in $sortLikeThis.

e.g.:

```
$output = [
    [
        'sort' => '5',
        'name' => 'Test 4',
    ],
    [
        'sort' => '3',
        'name' => 'Test 3',
    ],
    [
        'sort' => '7',
        'name' => 'Test',
    ],
    [
        'sort' => '7',
        'name' => 'Test 4',
    ],
    [
        'sort' => '1',
        'name' => 'Test 2',
    ],
]
```

What should I use?

Comment: Related, but not duplicate since this is a multidimensional array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-based-on-another-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort):

```
usort($unsorted, function($x, $y) use ($sortLikeThis)
{
   return array_search($x['sort'], $sortLikeThis) - array_search($y['sort'], $sortLikeThis);
});
```

Check the [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/nZ0CJ).

**Hint**: with current structure, you'll trigger `array_search()` (linear time) for each element, which may be slow. Thus, it can be optimized:

```
$sortLikeThis = array_flip($sortLikeThis);

usort($unsorted, function($x, $y) use ($sortLikeThis)
{
   return $sortLikeThis[$x['sort']] - $sortLikeThis[$y['sort']];
});
```

With this each lookup will be `O(1)` since it's a hash-table search.