# Sort an Array by values based on another Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How do I turn this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 123
            [name] => Board
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 133
            [name] => Staff
        )
)
```

Into:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 133
            [name] => Staff            
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 123
            [name] => Board  
        )
)
```

Based on this:

```
Array( 'Staff', 'Board'  )
```

In other words -- order an array of objects based on an array of values...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort an array based on another array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-based-on-another-array)

Comment: Don't use 6 year old answers as duplicates. PHP has been reinvented twice since then, see for example my use of [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to achieve this which wasn't possible back then (without `createfunction` hacks at least). Also, the solution isn't valid for the intended output of this question. This is therefore *not* a duplicate, at least of that question.

Comment: @derp it's not a duplicate question, as the source data doesn't even *remotely* look like the marked question structurally, and neither does the intended output, requiring a completely different solution. You're saying a BMW M3 and a Fiat 500 are identical cars because they both have a steering wheel.

Comment: The age isn't a problem, but it does seem different enough to not be a duplicate.  I have modified the title to hopefully make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ordering = ['Staff', 'Board'];
usort($myObjects, function($a, $b) use ($ordering) {
    $idx1 = array_search($a->name, $ordering);
    $idx2 = array_search($b->name, $ordering);
    if($idx1 == $idx2)
        return 0;
    elseif($idx1 < $idx2)
        return -1;
    return 1;
});
```

This example *does* assume that `$ordering` will contain all names it's going to encounter. If not you'll have to patch behaviour in there (can't do that because I don't know 'where' you want the unmatched items to sort to).

Comment: gah -- usort! I've been staring at the php manpage on that for over an hour... c'mon brain...

Comment: To your comment on $ordering -- what about those that are unmatched getting kicked to the end? Can't guarantee I'll get them all :P

Comment: `array_search` returns `FALSE` if no match was found. Therefore, for 2 unmatched objects, they are considered equal now (both `FALSE`), and could end up anywhere in the array, at random. You should either throw an error or introduce more defined behaviour there.