# Sort 1 array from another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have below 2 array values.

```
Array 1 - 2,1,3,0
Array 2 - 7,1,5,10.
```

Now i want 2 array like below.

```
Array 1 - 0,1,2,3
Array 2 - 10,1,7,5
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Did you take the site's [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: Yes i tried implode than from string... go through for each but it always give me just 10.

Comment: Read the full [Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) document from PHP.net and best of luck with your attempts and research. Come back here when you have a code with an issue to show us so we can offer help with it.

Comment: Even i also go through site. Pelase see below list.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array

Answer (score 0):

You could try sorting by value the first array, but maintain the index association. Then use the new order of keys to sort the other array:

```
asort($arr1);

$sorted_arr2 = [];
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val) {
  array_push($sorted_arr2, $arr2[$key]);
}
```