# Sort an array by another array of value priorities which may have more values than the original input array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, custom-sort

I have a comma separated string/array:

```
$input = "facebook,steam,tumblr,email,instagram,twitter,twitch,youtube,pinterest,amazon,disqus";
$input = explode(",", $input);
```

that I want to be ordered based on another array:

```
$order = "email,facebook,instagram,twitter,twitch,youtube,steam,pinterest,tumblr,amazon,disqus";
$order = explode(",", $order);
```

`$input` will always contain a value that is in `$order` and I want it to be sorted based on the order that it comes in `$order`. This is a bit tricky because `$input` will only contain a subset of values from `$order`.

For example, an input of `twitter,twitch,email,facebook` would return `email,facebook,twitter,twitch`

---

I have already found [This Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array) but it does not apply because I am not dealing with keys in my array.

Comment: Implementation of using the dupe target's advice: https://3v4l.org/P6kRQ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to do any fancy sorting algorithms. You can just do:

`array_intersect($order, $input);`

This will return an array containing all the values of `$order` that are present `$input`. And thankfully this function keeps the original order in `$order`.

---

Note: The order of the arguments to `array_intersect()` is important. Make sure you pass in `$order` first, since that is your reference array, then pass in `$input`, just like in the example above. Otherwise it will do the opposite, which is not what you want.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested, but may be useful to

```
   function orderByOtherArray($input, $orderedArray){
        $orderedInput = array();
        foreach($orderedArray as $key => $value){
            if(in_array($value, $input)){
                $orderedInput[] = $value;
                if(($key = array_search($value, $input)) !== false) {
                    unset($input[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach($input as $key => $value){
            $orderedInput[] = $value;
        }

        return $orderedInput;
    }
```

Comment: array_intersect() clean except intersection array element.