# PHP - sort an array by keys of another Array

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays and need to sort `$array1` based on the keys of `$array2`. Here are the arrays:

```
$array1 = array(
  'a1' => 'text1', 
  'a2' => 'text2', 
  'a3' => 'text3', 
  'a4' => 'text4'        
);

$array2 = array(
  'a2' => '1',       
  'a1' => '1', 
  'a3' => '0', 
  'a4' => '0'
);
```

After sorting, `$array1` should look like this.

```
$array1 =  array(
      'a2' => 'text2',           
      'a1' => 'text1', 
      'a3' => 'text3', 
      'a4' => 'text4'          
    );
```

I do not want to duplicate the array, but want `$array1` to be mutated. In addition, sometimes `$array2` will not contain all the keys in `$array1`.

Comment: What you have tried so far? It is not a question

Comment: Your problems makes no sense. Why would you sort one array by keys of another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an Array by keys based on another Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array) Oddly enough the name of that topic is the same. Did you search for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can foreach it with key.

```
$array1 = array(
  'a1' => 'text1', 
  'a2' => 'text2', 
  'a3' => 'text3', 
  'a4' => 'text4'        
);

$array2 = array(
  'a2' => '1',       
  'a1' => '1', 
  'a3' => '0', 
  'a4' => '0'
);

foreach($array2 as $key => $value){
    if(isset($array1[$key])) echo $array1[$key]."\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/65MrV