# sort a collection according to an array of IDs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have a collection like this named `categories` :

```
Collection {#447
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => array:6 [
      "pos" => "0"
      "col" => "1"
      "row" => "1"
      "size_x" => "2"
      "size_y" => "1"
      "cat_id" => "1"
    ]
    1 => array:6 [
      "pos" => "0"
      "col" => "3"
      "row" => "1"
      "size_x" => "1"
      "size_y" => "1"
      "cat_id" => "11"
    ]
    2 => array:6 [
      "pos" => "0"
      "col" => "1"
      "row" => "2"
      "size_x" => "2"
      "size_y" => "1"
      "cat_id" => "10"
    ]
]
}
```

On the other hand there is an array of IDs like this :

```
[11,10,1]
```

Now I want to sort element of that collection based on their `cat_id` index as sorted in an array. means I want result array to be like this :

```
Collection {#447
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => array:6 [
      "pos" => "0"
      "col" => "3"
      "row" => "1"
      "size_x" => "1"
      "size_y" => "1"
      "cat_id" => "11"
    ]
    1 => array:6 [
      "pos" => "0"
      "col" => "1"
      "row" => "2"
      "size_x" => "2"
      "size_y" => "1"
      "cat_id" => "10"
    ]
    2 =>array:6 [
      "pos" => "0"
      "col" => "1"
      "row" => "1"
      "size_x" => "2"
      "size_y" => "1"
      "cat_id" => "1"
    ] 
]
}
```

I used below codes but does not work properly:

```
$grids_arr  = [11,10,1];

$categories = $categories->sortBy(function ($model) use ($grids_arr) {
    return array_search($model->cat_id, $grids_arr);
});
```

**Update :**
This is my completed Code I'm using:

```
        $categories = Category::isTile()->get();

        $grids = collect(config('settings.data_grids'));// This is an array of IDs
        if ($grids->isNotEmpty()) {

            $grids_arr = $grids->pluck("cat_id")->toArray();
            $grids_arr = array_map('intval', $grids_arr); //convert string array elements to integer

            $categories = $categories->sortBy(function ($catg) use ($grids_arr) {
                return array_search($catg->cat_id, $grids_arr);
            });
        }
```

Comment: If you can index your `$categories` collection by `"cat_id"` you can then use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array

Comment: I'm not having any issues with the posted sortBy working correctly. Can you explain further? I can see a problem with having the same cat_id, since array_search() will return the first key found but my test of the above code came back alright.

Comment: is `cat_id` a primary key here?

Comment: @vivek_23, Yes it is.

Comment: I tried @jesus-erwin-suarez suggested approach, but I do not get correct result.

Comment: @A.B.Developer Try `return array_search($model['cat_id'], $grids_arr);`

Comment: same result unfortunately

Comment: @A.B.Developer You need to tag my name preceded with `@`. Also, making the correction as I said to you returns me the correct result on my machine. You will need to show us the what exact output you are receiving with the exact code you tried, that doesn't match your expected output.

Comment: @vivek_23, I added my completed codes.

Comment: @A.B.Developer ok but what's the output you are getting from that code? Also, why are you converting each element to integer since the array you showed has cat_id as string itself.

Comment: Ahmad Please check my new answer. I tested it. it Works well. va inke kheili mokhlesam ;)

Comment: does need to match the number of `$grids_arr` array elements and collection?

Comment: Yes it is needed

Comment: But some `cat_id` of my collection elements may not exists in the array and inverse.

Comment: In fact when searching an element of collection in array and does not found goes to end of result sorted collection.

Comment: what is isTile()?
I edit my answer. please check it. You just need to merge your array and query differences with the same array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have not responded because of differences between config('settings.data_grids') And   $categories. So edit your code as follows

Please add these three lines to your code:

```
$catIds = $categories->pluck('cat_id')->toArray(); //get all cat_id
$diff = array_diff($catIds, $grids_arr); // difference array from query
$grids_arr = array_merge($grids_arr , $diff); //merge difference with array
```

for example:

```
        $categories = Category::select('*')->get(); //for example
        $array = [
            [
                "pos" => "0",
                "col" => "1",
                "row" => "1",
                "size_x" => "2",
                "size_y" => "1",
                "cat_id" => 1,
            ],
            [
                "pos" => "0",
                "col" => "1",
                "row" => "2",
                "size_x" => "2",
                "size_y" => "1",
                "cat_id" => 10,
            ]
        ];
        $grids = collect($array);

        if ($grids->isNotEmpty()) {
            $grids_arr = $grids->pluck("cat_id")->toArray();
            $grids_arr = array_map('intval', $grids_arr); 

            //Please add these three lines to your code
            $catIds = $categories->pluck('cat_id')->toArray(); 
            $diff = array_diff($catIds, $grids_arr);
            $grids_arr = array_merge($grids_arr, $diff);
            //-----

            $sorted = $categories->sortBy(function ($model) use ($grids_arr) {
                return array_search($model->cat_id, $grids_arr);
            });


            return $sorted->values()->all();
        }
```

Comment: it really works. plz change $grids_arr  to your array

Comment: does need to match the number of `$grids_arr` array elements and collection?

Comment: hanooz javab nageraftam khob :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183814/discussion-between-ali-sharifi-and-a-b-developer).

Answer (score 2):

please check the code below.

```
$array = [
    0 => [
      "pos" => "0",
      "col" => "3",
      "row" => "1",
      "size_x" => "1",
      "size_y" => "1",
      "cat_id" => "11",
    ],
    1 => [
      "pos" => "0",
      "col" => "1",
      "row" => "2",
      "size_x" => "2",
      "size_y" => "1",
      "cat_id" => "10",

    ],
    2  => [

      "pos" => "0",
      "col" => "1",
      "row" => "1",
      "size_x" => "2",
      "size_y" => "1",
      "cat_id" => "1",
    ],
];

$array = array_reverse(array_sort($array, function ($value)
{
    return $value['cat_id'];
}));

dd($array);
```

Hope that it helps you.

Comment: I have a Collection not an array