# php sorting array by sequence in other array for mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, prepared-statement

I have a seeemingly banale question and I appreciate similar threads have been opened before, but I can't get it to work, so please bear with me:

Say I have an array `$field` with all field names of a mySQL INSERT statement. Then I have an associative array `$types` containing the (mysqli prepared statement) types of these fields, like so:

```
<?php

$fields = ["id","name","val","city"];
$type = ["name"=>"s","id"=>"i","city"=>"s","val"=>"d"];
```

The $type array has all values of $fields as key, but they aren't necessaryily in the same order. How would I generate a new array with the type abbreviations of all fields ..

```
$fieldtypes = ["s", "i", "d", "s"]
```

which I could than implode into the correct type string `"sids"` for the prepared statement.

I have been experimenting with

```
$try = array_replace(array_flip($fields),$type);
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array#) which works for the implode functionality, as the array elements are in the correct order now ...

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "i" ["name"]=> string(1) "s" ["val"]=> string(1) "d" ["city"]=> string(1) "s" }
```

... but I'm intrigued on how I would generate an array which also as the correct keys, like so:

```
 array(4) { ["0"]=> string(1) "i" ["1"]=> string(1) "s" ["2"]=> string(1) "d" ["3"]=> string(1) "s" }
```

Comment: What makes these keys "correct"? Anyway, just calling `array_values` on your resulting array will do the job.

Comment: Initialize `$type` array in the correct order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_reduce()`

```
$fields = ["id", "name", "val", "city"];
$type = ["name" => "s", "id" => "i", "city" => "s", "val" => "d"];
var_dump(array_reduce($fields, fn ($result, $item) => $result .= $type[$item]));
```

P.S. You can make life easier for yourself and bind every single parameter as a string. You don't need to worry about integers or floats as they can be easily cast from string by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the field name as key and generate your fieldtypes array

```php
$fields = ["id","name","val","city"];
$type = ["name"=>"s","id"=>"i","city"=>"s","val"=>"d"];
$fieldtypes = [];

foreach($fields as $field) {

    $fieldtypes[] = $type[$field];

}

print_r($fieldtypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$fields = ["id", "name", "val", "city"];
$type = ["name" => "s", "id" => "i", "city" => "s", "val" => "d"];
```

Use loop over `$fields` using `array_map` and take thier types from `$type` array.

```php
$fieldtypes = array_map(fn($v)=>$type[$v], $fields);
```

```php
print_r(array_combine($fields, $type));
```

**Prints:**

```
Array
(
    [id] => s
    [name] => i
    [val] => s
    [city] => d
)
```

> I would generate an array which also as the correct keys

```php
print_r($fieldtypes); //Array ( [0] => i [1] => s [2] => d [3] => s )
```